# can i run powershell script through selenium with firefox ide?

Tags: powershell, selenium

I am new to browser automation. I want to use selenium browser automation to automate webpage and then run a powershell script through selenium which will be doing some work in windows.

Let suppose , with selenium ide i opened a page in which there is a IP , now selenium should get this IP and pass to powershell so that powershell script can ping this IP and result from powershell script can be again sent to selenium so that it can send that info to webpage for submission.

New to Selenium so , ignore any mistakes

Answer (score 1):

After opening required page, copy the IP you want and use that to write require command in power shell script. Below sample code #python may useful to you

```
from subprocess import Popen
def createandExecuteFile(self):
    file = open("path to powershell  script", "w+")
    file.write("write command for powershell")
    file.close()
    p = Popen(["powershell.exe", "path to powershell script"], stdout=sys.stdout)
    p.communicate()
```

copy the response from the powershell and use where you want. Let me know if you have any issue.